# How to edit default css for .mat-select-panel in angular material?

Tags: angular-material

The default select box of angular material is using the following class:

```
.mat-select-panel{
    min-width: 112px;
    max-width: 280px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    max-height: 230px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

However, I want to change the max-height to something else? How can i do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [API for mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) has been updated and now allows you to specify additional classes for your panel using the `panelClass` input.  You can then override styles in a global class definition.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: I see my custom class added when using `<mat-select panelClass='my-class' ...>` through firefox web tools but I don't see styles applied.